# Gather rows and plot a stacked bar plot in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe which I would like to gather as each row as a year (2010-2019). From this, I would like to make a stacked bar plot, each stack in each year being a sentiment.

```
#Take all rows and bind them together.
y <- rbind(nrc2010,nrc2011,nrc2012,nrc2013,nrc2014,nrc2015,nrc2016,nrc2017,nrc2018,nrc2019)

#Looks like this
structure(list(anger = c(273, 334, 235, 498, 442, 750, 316, 490, 
326, 419), anticipation = c(518, 580, 522, 959, 806, 1164, 535, 
756, 386, 797), disgust = c(199, 202, 132, 354, 281, 459, 178, 
282, 175, 289), fear = c(405, 467, 372, 1042, 831, 1202, 540, 
848, 477, 799), joy = c(302, 324, 300, 498, 470, 758, 355, 494, 
242, 573), negative = c(703, 690, 540, 1296, 1076, 1549, 697, 
1060, 629, 994), positive = c(1205, 1364, 1126, 2317, 1974, 3048, 
1318, 2007, 921, 1918), sadness = c(291, 264, 210, 523, 380, 
607, 298, 461, 280, 376), surprise = c(174, 182, 173, 337, 312, 
466, 270, 476, 199, 407), trust = c(836, 958, 729, 1311, 1334, 
1979, 856, 1356, 562, 1225)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

@akrun showed how to do it for one singular row, but is there a way to do them all at once?

That is, each column is labeled the year with the count value in the cell.

```
nrc2010_2 <- nrc2010  %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = 'sentiment', values_to = 'count') %>% 
  arrange(desc(count))
```

So from this new table, create a stacked bar plot, x axis being the year, y axis being the count, and each stack in the bar is a sentiment for each year with legend indicating that fill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could get all the datasets into a `list` with `mget`, then bind the rows with `bind_rows` while creating a 'year' column from the `names` of the `list`, then reshape to 'long' format with `pivot_longer` and use `ggplot` to plot the bar plot

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(ggplot2)
mget(ls(pattern = '^nrc\\d{4}$')) %>%
   bind_rows(.id = 'year') %>% 
   mutate(year = str_remove(year, '^nrc')) %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = -year, names_to = 'sentiment', values_to = 'count') %>%  
   arrange(desc(count)) %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x = year, y = count, fill = sentiment)) +
           geom_bar(colour = 'black', stat = 'identity')
```

[image]

Comment: @JohnnyThomas I changed the code, can you check now

Comment: Okay great! The x-axis should just be year, not 'nrc' preceding. Additionally, do you have any color themes that can better distigish the stack. Maybe outlines?

Comment: @JohnnyThomas i removed the prefix with `str_remove`

Comment: Its great!!! the purple pink magenta all blend in with eachother, is there a way to put boxes around each block? I tried color= "black" and it made them all red..??

Comment: @JohnnyThomas Try something on your own as well buddy.

Comment: @JohnnyThomas change it to `geom_bar` as there is a clash with `geom_col`